# WSO2 Identity server and spring 3 REST api integration

Tags: spring, rest, oauth, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to use WSO2 Identity server for OAuth token management. Is there an api available for operations like request  token, validate a token and other relevant functions. I am trying to secure my spring3 REST web application using IS.

```
AS: Glassfish
Java : 1.6
FW: Spring3
Build tool:maven
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.. WSO2 Identity Server can be used to cater this requirement..

Please have a look at http://blog.facilelogin.com/2011/07/integrating-3-legged-oauth-with-xacml.html for further details...

Comment: Hi Prabath, thanks for the link. Can I skip the ESB. My flow would be..  1. Manage users IS 2. request a token (consumer App + IS) to access a service application 3. validate token ( service App + IS) 4. IS returns some user profile data 5. Further logic executed by service app depending on user profile/role.